# How To Get Google App Engine Dashboard Graph / CPU Usage in My Application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I Want Any of the following 2 Situations

1.) I Want To Show Google App Engine Dashboard Graph In My Java Application

```
                         ( or )
```

2.) I Want To Show CPU Usage / Time Band Width Etc in My Application

Do I need to use any API For that ? if yes please letme know

Thanks And Regards

Answer (score 1):

There's not currently an API for accessing billing or quota data for your App Engine app. The only way to access this is interactively.

Comment: Is there a policy on scraping this data?  I assume it would be unsupported, in the sense that you won't be going out of your way to not break a scraper script, but is there some explicit rule against *not* doing so?

Comment: @PeterRecore You should definitely read the Terms of Service. We've announced that we'll be releasing a monitoring API in future, though, which will provide an API for this sort of information.

Comment: This is pretty theoertical, because I don't need the data enough to bother trying to parse it out of the interface.  However, I did read the TOS and the only thing that looked relevant was this:

Comment: 2.3. You agree not to (a) access (or attempt to access) the administrative interface of the Service by any means other than through the interface that is provided by Google in connection with the Service...

Comment: As an engineer, I would say the interface is a HTTPS GET to a certain URL, and once I have the HTML, Google doesn't care how I parse it - Firefox, PERL, lynx, or a job in the Task Queue.  What I don't know is how the lawyers would interpret it.

Answer (score -1):

In the dashboard in "Chart" section there is a combo to select data to chart. There are *CPU seconds used*, *Bytes Sent/Second* and *Bytes Received/Second* metrics:

[image]

Comment: I want to Show that Graph / Reslut in My Java Application.

Comment: @okrasz, Rajeev knows how to view the graph in the dashboard.  The question is asking how to embed that graph in another webpage, or how to get the data programmatically.